# NuxtJS - Redirect all wrong url's to 404 page

Tags: vue.js, redirect, routes, vue-router, nuxt.js

Yo,

I have a question becouse i can't solve it in my way.
I need redirect all wrong urls ("example mywebsite.com/asdasdasdasd") to mywebsite.com/404. How can i do it? I try using a *.vue and _.vue in pages folder but when I try to type a wrong url my website crash on localhost either

Comment: Can you plz show us what have you tried that we could look?

Answer (score 1):

If you use nuxt.js in `universal` mode (which means that you have server-side code as well), then you can use Nuxt.js serverMiddleware.

You could create a new `/serverMiddleware/redirects.js` file with the redirect logic:

```
const redirects =
[
  { "from": "/asdasdasdasd", "to": "/404" },      
]

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  const redirect = redirects.find(r => r.from === req.url)
  if (redirect) {
    console.log(`301 redirect: ${redirect.from} => ${redirect.to}`)
    res.writeHead(301, { Location: redirect.to })
    res.end()
  } else {
    next()
  }
}
```

Then add this as a `serverMiddleware` in `nuxt.config.js`:

```
serverMiddleware: [
  '~/serverMiddleware/redirects'
]
```

This is the simplest solution if you have some URLs to redirect. You could change this code to redirect all urls with a given pattern.